# React Native pass parameters from Screen to Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to pass a parameter from a screen to the Tab Navigator. In this I want to use it. Following the corresponding lines from my App.tsx:

```
    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const AppStack = () => {

  const [chatcount, setChatcount] = React.useState(0);
  
  ...

  chatbadge = (number) => {

    setChatcount(number)
  };
  
  ...


  return(
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="..."
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: 'rgba(255,0,35, 1)',
        inactiveTintColor: 'rgba(255,0,35, 0.7)',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 235, 238)',
        activeBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 235, 238)',
        style: {backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 235, 238)'},
      }}
    >
        ...
      <Tab.Screen name="Chats" component={() => <Chats chatbadge={this.chatbadge}/>}/>
      ...
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
};

const App = () => {  
    return(
      <ActionSheetProvider>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext} >
          <NavigationContainer>
            <AppStack/>
          </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
      </ActionSheetProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Now I want to set the chatcount in my chats screen /Chats.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet, View, Text, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, AsyncStorage, Platform, TextInput, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
...
import { createStackNavigator  } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
...


import Chat from "../screens/Chat";
...

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function NavStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Chats" component={Chats}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={Chat}/>
      ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

class Chats extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._isMounted = false;

  }

  state = {
    data: [],
    value: ""
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this._isMounted && this.fetchData()
    this._isMounted && setInterval(() => this.fetchData(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    if(this._isMounted){
      const response = await fetch('...', {
        ....
      });
      const json = await response.json();
      this.setState({data: json});
      this.props.chatbadge(json)
    }
  }

  ...

  render(){
    ...
    const {navigation} = this.props
    return(
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        ...
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
});
```

this.props.chatbadge(json) shows an error that this.props.chatbadge is not defined. console.log(this.props.chatbadge) displayes "undefined".

I would be very happy about help.

Best regards
Lukas

Comment: you can use useContext hook like you used it for auth needs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext, i think it will solve your problem

Comment: Hi @Oleksii, thanks for youre help. I already use useContext fot the authentication. Can i use two Contexts at the same time?

Comment: you can use global context with corresponding reducers that will work with auth state and with the chatcount state

Comment: I have added changebadge: async data => {  } to my AuthContext. If I try to import it with   `import { AuthContext } from "../../App"` `static contextType = AuthContext;` I get the error that I try to define a invalid contextType.